# Who is healed when you Make Camp?

Tags: healing, ironsworn, moves

In Make Camp move, there are 2 options to heal your group:

> - Recuperate: Take +1 health for you and any companions
> - Partake: Suffer -1 supply and take +1 health for you and any companions.

**Does "any companions" mean one other ally, or all allies?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any companions means all your companions. It is in plural form.

> If you recuperate or partake, you can also apply those benefits to your companions (NPC assets—see page 39).

Please note that companion is **NPC asset**, not other player character, which is called **ally.**

So on a strong hit, you may recover maximum 2 health by choosing Recuperate and Partake options for **you and all your companions.**

Each player (ally) may also pick option for themselves, including the Recuperate or Partake to heal them and their own companions.

---

See also Move Glossary on page 56:

> “ALLIES / ALLY”
> An ally (page 25) is a character controlled by another player.